# How many chess games are required to be played if 9 players win 2 games against each other player?

Tags: intuition, recursion

How many chess games are required to be played if 9 players win 2 games against each other player?

Would the answer = 1152?

I got this because each player plays 8 games in 1 iteration (he cannot play against himself) and wins 1.
To win 1 game against every player, he plays 64 games. To win 2 games against every player, he plays 128 games. However, there are 8 other players who do the same so there are (128*9) games played? Is this correct?

Comment: To win a game against every player, (s)he plays $8$ games.

Comment: @andrénicolas so you're saying, 144 games are played? (8 games played for 1 player to win 1 game against everyone else, *2 to win 2 games which gives 16) There are 9 players so 16*9 = 144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably we are asked what is the **minimum** possible number of games. Draws are a standard part of chess. And if Player A beats B, she is likely to beat B again the next time, or draw. So the *actual* number of games played until every player has beaten every other player is likely to be very large. After this nod to reality, we calculate.

Each player has $16$ wins. There are $9$ players. Since there are no draws, the number of wins is the number of games.

Comment: So in effect 144 games at minimum are needed to be played. However, in a probabilistic scenario which includes draws, how many games would be needed to be played to ensure a 50% chance that everyone wins 2 games against everyone else?

Comment: Different problem. Hard to set up realistic assumptions. There are players who could give me a bishop handicap and beat me while drunk. Interesting question could be made, perhaps about a more probabilistic game.